# Obtener las primeras letras de un archivo. C++

Tags: c, string, archivo

Tengo un archivo .dat con nombres y necesito obtener solo la primera letra de cada nombre en minúsculas e imprimirlo, ya sea en pantalla o guardarlo en otro archivo. Por ejemplo:

nombres.dat:

Juan Perez

Jose Ramirez

Guadalupe Diaz

Resultado:

jp

jr

gd

Intento leer carácter por carácter y cuando encuentre un espacio, que tome i+1 que sería la primera letra del primer apellido después del espacio. Pero solo me imprime el puro archivo con los nombres completos, no sé qué falta.

Gracias.
Tengo este código hasta el momento:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 500

void leeArchivo(char[MAX]);
void inicial(char[MAX], char[MAX]);

int main(){
    char cad2[MAX], cad[MAX];
    leeArchivo(cad);
    inicial(cad, cad2);
    return 0;
}
void leeArchivo(char cad[MAX]){
    int i=0, l=0;
    FILE*nom;
    nom=fopen("nombres.dat", "r");
    if(nom!=NULL){
        while(!feof(nom)){
            cad[MAX]=fgetc(nom);
            if(cad[MAX]!=EOF){
                printf("%c", cad[MAX]);
            }
        }
        fclose(nom);
    }
    return;
}
void inicial(char cad[MAX], char cad2[MAX]){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; cad[MAX]=='\0'; i++){
        if(cad[i]==' '){
            cad[i+1];
            strncpy(cad2, cad, 1);
        }printf("%c", cad2[MAX]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Estas consciente de que no estás guardando los datos leídos del texto en `cad`? Mira y analiza bien esta linea `cad[MAX]=fgetc(nom);`

Comment: Sí pude resolverlo. No lo había notado. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes compartir tu solución posteando respondiendo a tu propia pregunta, esto ayuda a los demás usuarios y te da puntos por reputación!